# How to fix a layout on top of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a linear layout inside a scrollview and I want the the third element to stick to the top of the parent and remain visible while others are being scrolled up and when it's scrolled down, it returns back to it's original position. How can I handle such an even?

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
       <View1 />
       <View2 />
       <View3 />
       <View4 />
       <View5 />
        .
        .
        .
       <Viewn />
    <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When scrolling, as `View3` hits the head of the ScrollView, I want it to stay fix at the top and other elements to scroll under it. And on scroll down, when it returns back to its proper position.

What I want to do is define a "gone" View just before the ScrollView such that when the View reaches the head, I then make the View visible and then make it gone again on scroll down.
I've no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Without Snapshot or xml file we can't say properly. post something for that.

Comment: Use the <Relative layout> and the property of the relative layout child 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
   <View1 />
   <View2 />
   <View3 />
   <View4 />
   <View5 />
    .
    .
    .
   <Viewn />
<LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

```
 public class List1Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener{

    private boolean isFix = false; 
    private Object mData[];
    private int firstVisibleItem = 0;

    public List1Adapter(Object data[]) {
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    if(null != mData) return mData.length + 1;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData[position];
}

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Object dataItem;
        if(isFix && firstVisibleItem >= topViewIndex && position == firstVisibleItem) {
           dataItem = getItem(topViewIndex); 
        }
        if(null == convertView) {
            convertView = new View();
        }

        //render with your data.
    }

     void  onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){

          if(visibleItemCount > 0 && firstVisibleItem >= topViewIndex) {
              isFix = true;
          }else {
              isFix = false;
          }             
          this.firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
     }

 }
```

could you do in this way?

Comment: but the top element is part of the scrollview at some point, here it is fixed. Could you read my edit?

Comment: did you mean view3 must always be the top when scoll up?

Comment: when it reaches the top it stays there and the others continue

Comment: i think all is about adapter.you can control how to show your view.so you may do some logic in your adapter.hope can help.i update it.